# Extending ref keyword to another variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing wpf application.

I'm trying to pass object by reference using ref keyword and then pass it to another variable in constructor to change it later. But when I change the variable to which I passed the reference in constructor varaible doesn't change outside scope.

To explain, first I create variable and pass it to another window's constructor.

```
private void LocatonEditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var location = new Location(SelectedLocation.Name, SelectedLocation.X, SelectedLocation.Y, SelectedLocation.Update); 
        //Creating object
        var result =  new EditWindow(ref location,true).ShowDialog();
        //And passing it to another window with ref
    }
```

Here I assign variable to InitialLocation, if I try to change it here it works on outside variable.

```
 public partial class EditWindow : Window
{
    public EditWindow(ref Location location, bool isEdit)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitialLocation = location;
        //InitialLocation = ref location; //This is what I want my code to do 
        location.Name = "new"; //this changes varaiable outside scope
    }

    private Location InitialLocation;
```

Here I change InitialLocation but change doesn't persits outside the scope.

```
    private void ConfirmButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitialLocation = new Location(CurrentLocation.Name, CurrentLocation.X, CurrentLocation.Y, InitialLocation.Update);
        //But this doesn't change varaible outside scope

        this.Close();
    }
```

I want to keep object that was passed with ref until the window I passed it to is disposed. 
Is it possible to do without waiting for closed event?

Comment: What is `Location`? If it's a class rather than a struct, get rid of the `ref` keyword. A class is a reference type. Passing it doesn't create a copy. If it's a struct, make it a class and get rid of the `ref` keyword.

Comment: *"But this doesn't change varaible outside scope"* -- that makes no sense. Which scope? What variable? There are no locals in that method. If `InitialLocation` exists at all, it must be a class member. Your explanations don't help much and you haven't shared enough code to figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to declare InitialLocation as public property.

```
public partial class EditWindow : Window
{
    public EditWindow(Location location, bool isEdit)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitialLocation = location;
        location.Name = "new";
    }

    public Location InitialLocation { get; set; }

    private void ConfirmButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitialLocation = new Location(CurrentLocation.Name, CurrentLocation.X, CurrentLocation.Y, InitialLocation.Update);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

after editing read the value of that property:

```
private void LocatonEditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var location = new Location(SelectedLocation.Name, SelectedLocation.X, SelectedLocation.Y, SelectedLocation.Update); 

    var editWindow = new EditWindow(location, true);
    var result = editWindow.ShowDialog();

    var changedLocation = editWindow.InitialLocation;
}
```